# Excel Pivot Table Exclude one Row in Calculated Field

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In Microsoft Excel I want to have a pivot table that uses a calculated field for a row.  I would like the calculated Row to exlude the current year.  So I want two summary rows one with current year and one without.  The attachment in orange shows my desired result.

I know I can manually make the cell formula for each month, but I would like it to be automatic.  Any thoughts?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your row variable was called "Year", your column variable called "Month", E1 was one of the cells in your pivot table and your values variable was called "Score", you could do something like

```
=GETPIVOTDATA("Score",E1,"Month","Jan")-GETPIVOTDATA("Score",E1,"Month","Jan","Year",YEAR(NOW()))
```

and repeat for each month.

However you would need to leave room under the table for it to expand to avoid over-writing your orange cells.

The only other way I can think of is the obvious one of copying the whole pivot table and filtering on row labels, excluding 2015.

You can copy a pivot table by selecting the whole table (can use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> <kbd>Shift</kbd> <kbd>*</kbd>), right-clicking, selecting Copy and then pasting it somewhere else.

This is a mini-example showing the two methods.

[image]